# Why application (sysout/syserr) logs getting redirected to catalina.out do not have timestamps?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

Tomcat Version : 8.0.54
Logger: Tomcats internal logger juli

Tomcat generated logs have timestamp, 
whereas the application logs(sysout/syserr) which are getting redirected to catalina.out do not have timestamps.

Please suggest me how to add timestamp to application logs(sysout/syserr) which are getting redirected to catalina.out?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no reason the ouput logs of your application should have a timestamp unless you do it yourself within your application. Whether they are written in the sysout/syserr text files or catalina.out file.

Comment: Make sure your output has the %d field for dates, i.e. %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} or %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} as specified in https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need proper timestamps (and maybe logging levels) you'll either need to use a proper logger, or add them to your `System.out.println()` statements yourself.

Note, that `System.out` is not meant to be used for logging. In fact, two threads that write to sysout at the same time might as well interleave their output. Even character by character - and even more probably when you construct the output in various steps (e.g. using `print` with no `ln`)

Comment: @OlafKnock Thanks for the suggestion. Could you please suggest what are the external logger's which can be used to achieve the timestamp.

Comment: It's whatever you use anyway. Java Logging, Log4j - any logging system pays attention to timestamps and threading. You're not saying that you don't know that logging libraries exist, right?

Comment: @olafKnock i heared of log4j but has not used it.

Comment: @OlafKnock  is there anyway we can append timestamp to the system.out.println messages with tomcat juli logger?